# Difference between $# and ${#@}

Tags: bash, string-length

I was looking at the following code and found that both $# and ${#@} print the same value. Could someone tell me what's the difference between the two?

```
# length.sh

E_NO_ARGS=65

if [ $# -eq 0 ]  # Must have command-line args to demo script.
then
  echo "Please invoke this script with one or more command-line arguments."
  exit $E_NO_ARGS
fi  

var01=abcdEFGH28ij
echo "var01 = ${var01}"
echo "Length of var01 = ${#var01}"
# Now, let's try embedding a space.
var02="abcd EFGH28ij"
echo "var02 = ${var02}"
echo "Length of var02 = ${#var02}"

echo "Number of command-line arguments passed to script = ${#@}"
echo "Number of command-line arguments passed to script = $#"

exit 0
```

Comment: practically I think there is no difference.  `$#` is the number of command line arguments, `$@` is effectively an array of the command line arguments, and `${#@}` is the length of this array -- they should have the same value.

Comment: Note that the fact that `${#@}` expands to the number of positional parameters is a bashism. The POSIX standard leaves `${#@}` and `${#*}` undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per manual page ([3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

> `${#parameter}`
>
> Parameter length.  The length in  characters  of  the  value  of parameter  is  substituted.   *If  parameter is `*` or **`@`**, the value substituted is the number of positional parameters.*  If  parameter  is  an  array name subscripted by * or @, the value substituted is the number of elements in the array.

So `${#@}` is just a special case since `$#` is the usual way to express the number of positional parameters.